# Conformal mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

I'm studying Potential theory in the complex plane in Dr.Thomas Ransford book and I get stuck in proving that the mapping 
$$f\left( z \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( z-1 + \sqrt{\left( z- e^{i \alpha /2} \right)  \left( z - e^{-i\alpha /2} \right)   }   \right) $$

maps $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}\setminus K $ conformally onto $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}\setminus \overline{\Delta}{\left( 0; \sin{\left(\alpha /4   \right)  } \right)}$ where $K$ is the circular arc $\left\{e^{i \theta}: \left| \theta  \right| \leq \alpha /2  \right\}$ and $\overline{\Delta}{\left( 0; \sin{\left(\alpha /4   \right)  } \right)}$ is the closed ball centred at $0$ with radius $\sin{\alpha/4}$. The square root is chosen so that $f(z) = z+ O(1)$ as $z \to \infty$.

It is easyly see that $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}\setminus K $, but I have no idea to prove $f$ is bijective.

Any help would be appreciated. Regards.

Comment: Can you write $f$ as a composition of other analytic functions, which map biholomorphically onto some sequence of intermediate spaces?

Comment: @Travis I think I may set $f_1 (z) = z- \cos{( \alpha /2 )}$, $f_2 (z  ) = z^2 $ and $f_3 (z) = z + \sin^{2} (\alpha /2)$ and $f_4 (z) = \sqrt{z}$, and then I got stuck in finding the other analytic functions.